# Access to fetch at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular, spring-boot, heroku, cors, netlify

I would like to call backend (java/springboot) to create a login feature on my app. I invoke a jwtoken from frontend (angular) to backend. There is no problem to generate in backend and the frontend recieve the good jwtoken.

https://www.example.com/api/v1/authenticate

response :

```
jwtToken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdG9ja21hbmFnZXIiLCJleHAiOjE2NDMzODc1NjQsImlhdCI6MTY0MzM2OTU2NH0.mYl10_v5Dm3S6K0lM5uBOLs1x2rYwC76ZkJ9w6-QOTw1tE7xjiKxMIOiiU6QgwsKxqtDmz31aCEA4ePY2IzkUQ"
```

So far, so good

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/api/v1/authenticate
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200  (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

But I would like to GET a user with authentification in the header of the call

https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/find

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdG9ja21hbmFnZXIiLCJleHAiOjE2NDMzODc1NjQsImlhdCI6MTY0MzM2OTU2NH0.mYl10_v5Dm3S6K0lM5uBOLs1x2rYwC76ZkJ9w6-QOTw1tE7xjiKxMIOiiU6QgwsKxqtDmz31aCEA4ePY2IzkUQ
Payload : {username: "example", password: "password"}
```

Unfortunately there a CORS Error :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/find' from origin 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/find' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I need some Help, please :sweat_smile:

Comment: Your code would be interesting.

Comment: Cors is enabled by your server inside your api side, so that other than server domain can able to interact with your api.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by update my backend ;-)
I add `httpSecurity.cors()` in the `configure()` method;

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.cors();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(this.jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

The backend can now `getHeaders`, so Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running your app in the development mode using command "ng serve", if so then to avoid this CORS issue you can call your backend(java/springboot) REST api through proxy support. Please go through the below section in angular documentation to know more about proxying.

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: Indeed I use a local proxy to call the backend. I have no problem locally. I have this problem when I deploy to production.

I use Netlify for the frontend deployment, and Heroku for the backend.

The error message :  "Access to fetch at 'https://www.backend.heroku.com/api/v1/users/find' from origin 'https://www.frontend.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

I need some help for this issue, because this is a long standing problem...

Comment: The problem seems come from the backend cannot get the header of request. request.getHeader( 'Authorization' ) = null. But there is an autorization in the header of request. Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdG9ja21hbmFnZXIiLCJleHAiOjE2NDMzODc1NjQsImlhdCI6MTY0MzM2OTU2NH0.mYl10_v5Dm3S6K0lM5uBOLs1x2rYwC76ZkJ9w6-QOTw1tE7xjiKxMIOiiU6QgwsKxqtDmz31aCEA4ePY2IzkUQ. So I don't understand this issue^^